# How to empty debug.log when file size is above xyMB?

Tags: debug

Sometimes I forget to empty my debug.log file (or that it exists) and after trying to get around a bug, I find it having simply too much content to open it in ex. the basic Windows Text Editor.

Part of my wp-config.php file:

```
error_reporting( E_ALL );
define( 'WP_DEBUG',         true );
define( 'SAVEQUERIES',      true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG',     true ); // file: /core_root/wp-content/debug.log
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
```

**Question:** Is there a way to do this via Wordpress, or do I have to do it with basic php functions?

Comment: Notepad++ or gVim should be able to open the file for you, if you don't need a code solution.

Comment: @jjeaton Thanks. But I'm really searching for a solution to not have a xyGB file in my dev environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a cron job for a function which checks the file size and runs `unlink( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/debug.log' )` if necessary.